# Regex to use to validate that a json parameter can only take 2 types of int values ​as a string

Tags: java, regex, quarkus, hibernate-validator

Good Morning

I am currently working on a microservice in which one of its input parameters indicates the type of platform (if it is postpaid/prepaid), for this an int type value is sent as a string, that is, if it is prepaid it has a value of 1 , while if it is postpaid it has a value of 2.

The question is that if I send a value of 3 or 4, for example, hiberante validator validates it and returns a controlled error, but I have not gotten the regex expression that helps me to fulfill the request, so I currently have it:

[image]

```
@Data
public class FindSimCardPukCodeCSRequest {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1,max=10)
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp="^\\d+$")
    @JsonProperty("subscriberId")
    @Schema(description = "Numero movil del ciente")
    private String subscriberId;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1)
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "[12]", flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    @JsonProperty("idPaidPlatformCustomer")
    @Schema(description = "Id asociado a la plataforma")
    private String idPaidPlatformCustomer;
}
```

This is how the request looks at the json level:

```
{
    "FindSimCardPukCodeCS": {
        "Header": {
            "country": "VE",
            "lang": "ES",
            "entity": "TMVE",
            "system": 76,
            "subsystem": "APP",
            "originator": "VE:TMVE:97:APP",
            "userId": "04142985219",
            "operation": "FindSimCardPukCodeCS",
            "destination": "VE:TMVE:93:RSB",
            "timestamp": "2021-01-20T10:23:23.233-04:00",
            "msgType": "REQUEST"
        },
        "Body": {
            "findSimCardPukCodeCSRequest": {
                "subscriberId": "4240080890",
                "idPaidPlatformCustomer": "3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the regular expression to use, the field should only be valid if it has a value of type 1 or 2 as a string

Comment: Try: `@Pattern(regexp = "^[12]$")`

Comment: Why not an enum?